# register keyword in inline function included from C

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a mixed C and C++ project. Lately it happened that external library I have no control over added an inline function containing `register` keyword to header. For simplicity let's assume header looks like this:

```
// external_header.h
inline int do_stuff() {
  register int res = 1;
  return res;
}

// some functions declarations without name mangling
```

And let's assume this is my code (as usless as it is):

```
// my_code.cpp

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

#include <external_header.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main(inc argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling my_code.cpp with C++17 switch gives error like this:

> error: ISO C++17 does not allow ‘register’ storage class specifier [-Werror=register]

Can there be anything done to work around this error? If so, what is to be done?

Comment: This looks like a C++ problem, not a mixing problem from the looks of that error message.

Comment: @BlueStaggo It is problem with compatibility. C++ dropped support for some of old C features. But whatever - I just want it solved ;)

Comment: If that external header has include guards then you can create your own variant of this header with alternative content, suppress inclusion of the original header by defining include guard macro and including your own header instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using compiler options, you can disable the `-Werror` flag for this warning only:

```
-Werror -Wno-error=register
```

Or you can disable this warning altogether:

```
-Wno-register
```

Or within the code you could use preprocessor macro to remove this keyword. Note that replacing keywords (even unused ones like `register`) is Undefined Behaviour.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

#define register

#include <external_header.h>

#undef register

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

If the C header isn't written in the common subset of C and C++ - and in your case it isn't - then you cannot include it in C++.

If you have no control over the header, then what you can do instead is write a header of your own that *is* written in valid C++. In order to use the problematic function, you can write a non-inline wrapper function in C where the non C++ header can be included, and delegate to the inline function.

Example:

```
// external_header.hpp
// ... imagine header guard of your choice here ...
extern "C"{
    int do_stuff_cpp(); // this is valid C++
    // some functions declarations without name mangling
}

// external_header_cpp.c
#include "external_header.h"
int do_stuff_cpp()
{
    return do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: It is great solution if the header is relatively small and there is not much code using it already. Sadly this is not the case